# Why is numpy vectorized function apparently called an extra time?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a numpy object array containing several lists of index numbers:

```
>>> idxLsts = np.array([[1], [0, 2]], dtype=object)
```

I define a vectorized function to append a value to each list:

```
>>> idx = 99  
>>> f = np.vectorize(lambda idxLst: idxLst.append(idx))
```

I invoke the function. I don't care about the return value, just the side effect.

```
>>> f(idxLsts)  
array([None, None], dtype=object)
```

The index 99 was added twice to the first list. Why? I'm stumped.

```
>>> idxLsts
array([[1, 99, 99], [0, 2, 99]], dtype=object)
```

With other values of idxLsts, it doesn't happen:

```
>>> idxLsts = np.array([[1, 2], [0, 2, 4]], dtype=object)
>>> f(idxLsts)
array([None, None], dtype=object)
>>> idxLsts
array([[1, 2, 99], [0, 2, 4, 99]], dtype=object)
```

My suspicion is it's related to the documentation which says: "Define a vectorized function which takes a ***nested*** sequence of objects or numpy arrays as inputs and returns a numpy array as output. The vectorized function evaluates pyfunc over successive tuples of the input arrays like the python map function, except it uses the broadcasting rules of numpy."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `vectorize` docstring:

> ```
> The data type of the output of `vectorized` is determined by calling
> the function with the first element of the input.  This can be avoided
> by specifying the `otypes` argument.
> ```

And from the code:

```
        theout = self.thefunc(*newargs)
```

This is an extra call to `thefunc`, used to determine the output type. This is why the first element is getting two `99`s appended.

This behavior happens in your second case as well:

```
import numpy as np
idxLsts = np.array([[1, 2], [0,2,4]], dtype = object)
idx = 99
f = np.vectorize(lambda x: x.append(idx))
f(idxLsts)
print(idxLsts)
```

yields

```
[[1, 2, 99, 99] [0, 2, 4, 99]]
```

---

You could use `np.frompyfunc` instead of `np.vectorize`:

```
import numpy as np
idxLsts = np.array([[1, 2], [0,2,4]], dtype = object)
idx = 99
f = np.frompyfunc(lambda x: x.append(idx), 1, 1)
f(idxLsts)
print(idxLsts)
```

yields

```
[[1, 2, 99] [0, 2, 4, 99]]
```

Comment: A minor footnote: I have found that although the docs say that this behavior "can be avoided by specifying the `otypes` argument," supplying `otypes` does not prevent the double-call (at least in version 1.6.2).

Comment: @senderle: Thanks. I was not able to avoid the double-call either, except by specifying `otypes = '?'`, **and** `f.nout = 1` **and** `f.lastcallargs = 1`, which seems a bit crazy :)